# Modifying platform/frameworks/base package

Tags: java, android, class-library, recompile

I'm planning to modify some bits in the platform/frameworks/base project in Android Donut r2. The modifications are very small and goes into java packages `android.graphics` and `android.text` (the API isn't affected).

What jar libraries do I have to copy from the recompiled platform? the modifications are small and I don't want to replace the whole system.. I'm trying to replace specific jar libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how many 'bits' need modifying, but perhaps you could just try to extend the classes you need?

Comment: This isn't a solution for my me because I'm trying to modify internal core text handling. I will implement real BiDi and add reshaping for Arabic words.